# How to get an output console in an Ogre project under MacOSX?

Tags: macos, api, console, porting, ogre3d

I'm working on a project using Ogre3D. We recently ported our project to MacOSX but there are some things that were linked to the Windows API. In particular I don't know how this should be translated:

```
#if defined( __WIN32__ ) || defined( _WIN32 )
    AllocConsole();
#endif
```

It would be nice to port the project under Linux someday, so is there an Unix-compatible way to allocate a console for standard output/input?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From UNIX point of view, since I'm not that experienced in Mac-specific development.

A console is "allocated" by default. You cannot order the OS to open a console though. You could tell the IDE you are using to open it in a terminal, or, if it supports that, create your current application as a Console Application, despite using GUI.

What do I mean by saying that console is allocated by default? Each process actually gets its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (file identifiers 0, 1 and 2) from the calling process. So unless calling process (`bash`, Finder, whatever) conveniently forgets to *leave* those open, you always have a console open ... but perhaps invisible?

Easiest way to get a console is to launch the application from Terminal as Finder would do it from GUI. Remember, .apps are actually folders:

```
/projects/myapp$ ./BuiltApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/BuiltApplication
```

Finder sets the current working directory to the folder where  the .app bundle is located, so the above emulates it all best.

Additionally, take a look at the Console application at `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`, included with MacOS. Console is usually used for viewing stdout and stderr. I cannot test this since I'm not on Mac, but I've actually found some sources that say that stdout and stderr should be redirected there. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364564/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-os-x-application-on-the-console-or-to-a-file/365000#365000):

> You can use Console.app to see the output of applications launched in the normal manner, because the launch infrastructure specifically sends their `stdout` and `stderr` there. You can also use the `asl` routines to query the log, or perform more sophisticated logging if you so desire.