# Output of NSLog for applications running without XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm distributing my first Mac OS X application to beta-testers and i have a silly question but have trouble finding the answer :

"Where is the output of NSLog calls once your application is packaged into a .app bundle ?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the output of an os x application on the console, or to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364564/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-os-x-application-on-the-console-or-to-a-file)

Comment: indeed it kind of is... :( thanks and sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henry,

Asked and answered: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364564/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-os-x-application-on-the-console-or-to-a-file)

Basically, stdout/stderr go to the console log, visible with the Console.app.

Answer (score 0):

*There is not so elegant but quite user-friendly method. It is an Organizer. Yes, I know, it is a part of Xcode. You can blame me for the fact that my answer is supposed to reveal some xcodeless method **but** you can use the method described below even if you have no source code. It could be useful in some cases.*

So, here is the method:

1. Open Xcode.
2. Select `Window -> Organizer` menu item.
3. Select your plugged iDevice there.
4. On your iDevice check that `Settings -> Developer -> Logging` switch control is on.
5. Launch the app.
6. In Organizer select `Device Logs` tab. There are all the logs of your device to the moment.

If there are no logs at `Device Logs` tab check #4, then reconnect the device. In some case you should then restart Xcode.