# How to display Xcode output into terminal.app

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I'm having issues with getting xcode project output to display into my terminal.app. I can get the terminal to pop up on run, but how do I get the "output" to display into the terminal.app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All NSLog are printed automatically in System log in Terminal.app.

> If you want to see the results directly in your Terminal, you need to
>   run the built product as a child of the Terminal, which means using
>   something like
>   /path/debug/build/MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram to launch the
>   app.

[From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364564/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-os-x-application-on-the-console-or-to-a-file).

---

EDIT:

If you want to redirect the NSLog to a file use :

```
-(void) redirectNSLogToFile {
     NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *filePath=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *logPath=[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LogFile.txt"];
     freopen([logpath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

Comment: So, I don't have to use the output files in xcdoe?

Comment: What I really want is to get the apps output and export it into a text file. Is that possible or am I over thinking things?

Comment: If you look at the pic you can see the output that I'm getting from my app in the "all output" screen. Is there a way to display that into a text file and/or terminal?

Comment: I like this, but I made the file LogFile.txt and nothing happened. Where would I stick this method?

Comment: whereever you write nslog, replace this with that

Comment: and always point to user by @username, the i will get the message :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app in Xcode all the output is in the  'All Output' pane.  If you want to preserve that just: select it, copy it, and paste it into a file (created with TextEdit or whatever).

By default, running your app in the Terminal.app won't preserve the output.  You can use Unix pipes/redirects to get it into a file with, for example:

```
  $ /path/to/myapp > /path/to/LogFile.txt
```

Comment: Where would I put this redirect?

Comment: The above is what you would type in the Terminal.app, to the shell (which is what actually runs in the Terminal.app).

Comment: Getting this error message  /path/to/LogFile.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: The notation '/path/to' means that you need to provide that information.  The error message is saying that '/path/to' doesn't exist; which is true.  If you want 'LogFile.txt' to be in your 'Home' folder use "~/LogFile.txt"; if you want it on your Desktop use "~/Desktop/LogFile.txt"