# How to get the output of an Apple Script on the console if it's packaged as an app?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm writing an Apple Script and exporting it as an Application. I need this application to output data to standard output. I tried the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365062/502818) and had no luck.

Here is a sample Apple Script:

```
return "Hello World!"
```

When I run this script using osascript I get a correct output:

```
$ osascript test.scpt
Hello World
```

But when I export the script as an Application and then do

```
$ test.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

I get no any output.

I need it to send a standard output that can be used in a pipe, e.g. like this:

```
$ test.app/Contents/MacOS/applet | less
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `osascript` command on a AppleScript file or on an AppleScript saved as an Application

```
osascript test.app | less
```