# MySQL Workbench: Connecting to database automatically on the startup

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

Currently, I have to:

1. Launch MySQLWorkBench 8.0
2. Click on the DB that I need to connect to
   [image]

I'd like to:

1. Launch MySQLWorkBench 8.0
2. MySQLWorkBench automatically connects to this DB without me clicking on it

I need to re-open MySQLWorkbench during my day a lot an hence would like to eliminate this step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought was: if you need it so often, don't close it.

But it's easy to accomplish what you want if you are willing to run MySQL Workbench from a script. For instance open `/Application` in a terminal and run this command (on macOS):

```
open -a MySQLWorkbench.app --args --query "Localhost 8.0"
```

where "Localhost 8.0" must be changed to a connection name you want to open. This will open the SQL IDE for that server. You can put the call into a shell script and run that instead of the application itself.

Instead of `--query` use `--help` to print a list of supported commands:

```
MySQLWorkbench [<options>] [<name of a model file or sql script>]
Options:
    --admin <instance>            Open a administration tab to the named instance
    --configdir <path>            Specify configuration directory location, default is platform specific.
    -h, --help                    Show help options   
    --log-level <level>           Valid levels are: error, warning, info, debug1, debug2, debug3
    --log-to-stderr               Also log to stderr  
    --migration                   Open a migration wizard tab
    --model <model file>          Open the given EER model file
    --open                        Open the given file at startup (deprecated, use script, model etc.)
    --query <connection>|<connection string>Open a query tab and ask for connection if nothing is specified.
If named connection is specified it will be opened,
else connection will be created based on the given connection string,
    --quit-when-done              Quit Workbench when the script is done
    --run <code>                  Execute the given Python code
    --run-python <code>           Execute Python code from a file
    --run-script <file>           Execute Python code from a file
    --script <sql file>           Open the given SQL file in an connection, best in conjunction with a query parameter
    --upgrade-mysql-dbs           Open a migration wizard tab
    -v, --verbose                 Enable diagnostics output
    --version                     Show Workbench version number and exit
```

However, this doesn't show any output when using the `open` command (due to the way it works, see also [How to get the output of an os x application on the console, or to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364564/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-os-x-application-on-the-console-or-to-a-file)), but you can run the app binary directly (instead of the app bundle as shown above), like this:

```
./MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench --help
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution! As i see command work only first time, if Workbench already running args will be ignored. Except when i run app as new instance. Is there any way to launch my query for current instance?

Comment: MySQL workbench parses command line params only on startup, thus you cannot use a running instance with new parameters.

Comment: Hey @MikeLischke.
I run the following command, and it opens the app and connects to the database:
```"C:\..\MySQLWorkbench.exe" --query testdb```

However when I add ```--script C:\..\23.10.20.sql``` or ```--open C:\..\23.10.20.sql``` they have no effect. I only get the app connected to the database. I combine them like:

```"C:\..\MySQLWorkbench.exe" --query testdb --script C:\..\23.10.20.sql```
Is that the right way to combine them?

I asked this question here but no one answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64595764/how-do-i-run-2-options-of-mysql-workbench-together