# How do I run 2 options of mysql Workbench together?

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write a command-line script which will

- open Workbench
- connect to the specified database
- open an sql file
- run it
- export the results into a text file

I made use of workbench's guide for command-line guide from (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-command-line-options.html) up to the point of opening the app and connecting to the database. However, I can't combine the options. The options I write after "connect to database" are not read or run properly.

My question is how to combine/pipe them together.

The following command runs the app and connects to the database:

```
"C:\..\MySQLWorkbench.exe" --query testdb
```

When I add `--script C:\..\23.10.20.sql` or `--open C:\..\23.10.20.sql` they have no effect. I only get the app connected to the database with an empty window.
I combine them like:

```
"C:\..\MySQLWorkbench.exe" --query testdb --script C:\..\23.10.20.sql
```

Is that the right way to combine them?

**Edit:** By trying two other options together, I confirmed that this is not the right way. I still need an answer for how to run 2 options one after the other.

The options from the workbench's guide I use are:

```
--query [connection|connection_string]:

Connection: Open a named connection.

--model modelfile: open the given EER model file.

--script script: Open the given SQL file in a connection, typically used with the --query parameter.

--run code: Execute the given code using the default language for GRT shell.

--open file: Open the given file at startup. Deprecated, so instead use specific types such as --script or --model.
```

Note: There is a note in this guide saying one dash (-) should be used for Windows instead of two (--). Although I am using Windows, that is not the case for me. The options are only run when I use two dashes. With one dash, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WB to export a result, only to open a specific connection and run a query or to run a python script. In principle it would be possible to use Python to export the data, but this is quite a lot of work for a small effect.

Instead I recommend not to use WB at all and instead work directly with MySQL in your script. A GUI is not well suited to do terminal work.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however WB guide that I provided the link in my question specifically explains that ```--script``` can be used with ```--query```. 

Check this: ```--script script: Open the given SQL file in a connection, typically used with the --query parameter.```. If multiple options can't be used together or piped, what is the use of having a command-line function for one single option? 

I found that functionality in SSMS and it worked just fine. Still, I would like to know how 2 options can be used together.

Comment: My comment was specifically for your intended workflow of using the command line parameters, open a connection and export results. Otherwise yes, you can combine `--script` and `--query`. The order you specify them doesn't matter. If they don't work then you might have hit a bug.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to fix that bug? I tried everything I could. I even tried to contact SQL Workbench website but I couldn't. 
Even combining ```--script``` and ```--query``` would be great.